# IBM ACE Running the Transformation Advisor tool generates empty report

Tags: ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus

I'm referring section -3 (Running the Transformation Advisor tool)in the below link and it generates an empty report with no records.
https://developer.ibm.com/integration/blog/2020/02/20/modernizing-integration-migration-from-iib-to-app-connect-running-on-ibm-cloud-pak-for-integrationcp4i/

Steps ->
I used mqsibackupbroker in IIB 10 in "SLES" VERSION="11.4" to take a backup of the broker components.
mqsibackupbroker INODE -d . -a backupbroker.zip and the result was successful.
Copied the zip file to a windows 10 OS and opened IBM ACE 11.0.0.09 command console and executed the below command to generate the transformation advisor report.
C:\TADemo>TADataCollector ace run C:\backupbroker.zip
All output will be saved to the C:\TADemo directory.
Command 'run' completed successfully.

Questions

1. Can I take up a backup from mqsibackupbroker from SLES and generate a report using TADataCollector in windows?
2. do I need to deploy all the bar files running in SLES to the windows environment and generate reports?
   I did backup and TADataCollector in windows and I'm able to generate reports successfully in windows.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the response to each of your questions:

> 1. Can I take up a backup from mqsibackupbroker from SLES and generate
>    a report using TADataCollector in windows?

Yes, absolutely.

> 2. do I need to deploy all the bar files running in SLES to the windows environment
>    and generate reports? I did backup and TADataCollector in windows and I'm able to
>    generate reports successfully in windows.

You just have to take the backup of the broker created using mqsibackupbroker in IIB 10 and generate your report.

In general, this report advises you on what would be the complexity of changes required to migrate IIB v10 and a estimated effort in days. Again, I think this report is more targeted towards migration from IIB node to IBM ACE microservices architecture. The following document gives various approach one can take towards migration of IIB to ACE.

https://community.ibm.com/HigherLogic/System/DownloadDocumentFile.ashx?DocumentFileKey=8ce6711b-dad3-b031-ab12-2ef7e5a5a0fd&forceDialog=0